# Make Text editable on (onPress)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i make a some text editable when  user  press button ?

```
 <View style={styles.inner}>
          <Text style={styles.t1}>Name</Text>
          <Text style={styles.t2}
          onPress={this.updateText}>{this.state.txt}</Text> 
      </View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the button toggle a state variable indicating if we are in edit mode and display a `TextInput` instead of `Text` if we are in edit mode:

```
<View style={styles.inner}>
  <Text style={styles.t1}> Name </Text>

  { this.state.isEditing ?
    <TextInput
      value={this.state.txt}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ txt: value })}
      autoFocus
      onBlur={() => this.setState({ isEditing: false })}
    /> :
    <Text
      style={styles.t2}
      onPress={() => this.setState({ isEditing: true })}
    >
      {this.state.txt}
    </Text> 
  }
</View>
```

Answer (score 5):

Similar to Travis's answer but you can just toggle the `editable` prop on the textInput. You can add `handleEditable` to the button's onPress and that will make the textInput editable.

```
handleEditable = () => this.setState({ editable: true })
...
...
<TextInput
  value={this.state.text}
  onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
  editable={this.state.editable}
/>
```